# Populate radiobuttons from database android

Tags: android, database, radio-button, populate

i'm developing a driving school test app and I need some help.

I have xml file like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget28"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#AAC1E2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget29"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/i1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/e1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enun"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/i2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/e2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enun"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

... x 30 times and a button that will correct the test and show if you passed or not. You pass the test when you fail 3 questions or less.

Questions are stored this way:

Id_question Id_topic Id_test Question AnswerA AnswerB AnswerC AnswerOK Image

- Id_question Id_topic and id_test are integer fields
- Question and AnswerA-C are text fields
- AnswerOK is an integer field. If AnswerA is OK = 1, AnswerB = 2, AnswerC = 3
- Image is the name of the related image, extracted from resources folder.

I use a database to populate every field in the xml. Images and questions are extracted from database this way:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
    Cursor c = adbh.query(bundle.getString("test")); 
    //"test"-->"SELECT question, image FROM table WHERE id_test = 1"

        Integer i = 1;

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String path = c.getString(index);
                String nimage = "i"+i;
                int idImage = getResources().getIdentifier(nimage, "id", this.getPackageName());
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(idImage);
                int idDrawable = getResources().getIdentifier(ruta, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
                image.setImageResource(idDrawable);

                String nenun = "e"+i;
                String enun = c.getString(anotherIndex);
                int idEnun = getResources().getIdentifier(nenun, "id", this.getPackageName());
                TextView txtenun = (TextView) findViewById(idEnun);
                txtenun.setText(enun);

                i++;
            } while (c.moveToNext());
```

How can I populate radiobuttons? The query would be "SELECT AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC from table WHERE id_test = 1"

And my last question is how can I correct the test. I think on storing radiobutton pressed (I don't know exactly how) in an array and then compare with correct answers. The query would be "SELECT AnswerOK from table WHERE id_test = 1".

Example:

Array of answered questions:
    1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 1 3 2...
Array of correct answers:
    3 2 1 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2...

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
    if (a[i] == b[i])
    numberOfRightAnswers++;
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I populate radiobuttons? The query would be "SELECT AnswerA,
>   AnswerB, AnswerC from table WHERE id_test = 1"

Will probably want to select those values directly in the first query, so instead of :

```
Cursor c = adbh.query(bundle.getString("test")); 
    //"test"-->"SELECT question, image FROM table WHERE id_test = 1"
```

will have:

```
Cursor c = adbh.query(bundle.getString("test")); 
    //"test"-->"SELECT question, AnswerA,  AnswerB, AnswerC, image FROM table WHERE id_test = 1"
```

Then in that `while` loop assign the text to the `RadioButton`s like you did for `TextView txtenun`.

> And my last question is how can I correct the test. I think on storing
>   radiobutton pressed (I don't know exactly how) in an array and then
>   compare with correct answers.

Add a `OnCheckedChangeListener()` to all of your `RadioGroup`s. In that listener you'll get the `RadioGroup` where the user checked something and the id of the checked `RadioButton`. Use that to construct the array of correct answers.

**Some advices:**

Maybe you should modify your layout and your current approach. Making the user scroll your 30 question layout might not be such a good idea, also you're loading many resources although the user will not actually see them until it gets to that particular question(I don't know the size of your image, if they are small this probably isn't  an issue). You're other alternatives are a `ListView` layout or a simple layout of one question that you populate on demand depending on which questions is the user at. My advice would be the second option. That option will also help you avoid the `getIdentifier` method calls, this method is slower then the `findViewById` and should be avoided. Bellow is a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#AAC1E2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/questionImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/questionText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enun"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/previousQuestion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="previous" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/validateTest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="validate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextQuestion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="next" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

You'll make a query for all the question in that test(including all the data) and start with a static field `int counter = 0`. When the app is started you'll move the cursor to the counter value(which is 0 at the start):

```
c.moveToPosition(counter);
```

and use the values from that row to populate the above question layout:

```
ImageView questionImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.questionImage);
int idDrawable = getResources().getIdentifier(ruta, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
   questionImage.setImageResource(idDrawable);

String enun = c.getString(anotherIndex);
TextView txtenun = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionText);
txtenun.setText(enun);
// will do the same to populate the other parts of the question from the cursor
```

When the user presses the `nextQuestion` `Button` you'll increment the `counter` value(you should do some checks so you don't go overboard the 30 questions), move the cursor to the `counter` position again and then populate the layout like above. When the user presses previousQuestion you decrement `counter`, move the cursor and again populate the layout with data.
Also you'll add only one `OnCheckedChangeListener` to your `RadioGroup`. When that listener fires you should store the question id(from the `counter` value you should be able to tell on which question you are) and the selected `RadioButton` in a data structure(probably a `HashMap`), retrieve the correct answers for the test from the database and see if the user it's a good driver.

Also you could(probably) optimize your database.

**Edit:**

```
private ArrayList<Integer> responses = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // this will hold the number of the correct answer. Note that this will work if the user answers question one after the other
// if the user skips question you'll get in trouble, this is one of the reasons why your design is not so good.

String rg = "radioGroup" + i;
int idRg = getResources().getIdentifier(rg, "id", this.getPackageName());
RadioGroup radioGroup = (TextView) findViewById(idRg);
radioGroup.setOnChekedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
       public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (group.getChildAt(0).getId() == checkedId) {
               responses.add(0); // the first answer was checked
            } else if (group.getChildAt(1).getId() == checkedId) {
               responses.add(1); // the first answer was checked
            } else if (group.getChildAt(2).getId() == checkedId) {
               responses.add(2); // the first answer was checked
            }
      } 
});
```

Comment: I find very useful your advices. I need this kind of layout because in the actual exam you can navigate easily between questions, having all at once before your eyes :) Images are not a problem, they all are about 20 kb.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of one of the radiobutton listeners?

Comment: This would add a "0", "1" or "2" that I can compare to "0", "1" or "2" extracted from my database, right? Thank you @Luksprog.

Comment: @luismiyu Yes(but those are `integer` values, so is your `AnswerOK` from the database). Keep in mind that if the user jumps one of the question it will mess your correct answers `ArrayList` so be carefull.

Comment: I forced the first of radiobuttons always checked with 'rg.check(rb1);' in the loop so I think this would solve skipped response trouble... I cannot access "responses" ArrayList from the listener, it must be final. Doing so results in Force Close!

Comment: @luismiyu Make the `responses` `ArrayList` as a field in the class.

Comment: @luismiyu I don't know if you managed to follow my answer but here is a small sample activity http://pastebin.com/NFDKaMR1 you could look at.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look. I'm now working on correct() method. I was using two int[] but I'll check your option :)

Comment: Your code is working just fine, thanks a lot! Now I'm trying to store "Test name", ca and ra into a database to show statistics... and everything will be over :D

Comment: @luismiyu That shouldn't be so hard to do where you check the use answers.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Luksprog answer this is my finally working loop:

```
Cursor c = adbh.query(bundle.getString("test"));

    Integer i = 1;

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String ruta = c.getString(4);
            String nimage = "i" + i;
            int idImage = getResources().getIdentifier(nimage, "id",
                    this.getPackageName());
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(idImage);
            int idDrawable = getResources().getIdentifier(ruta, "drawable",
                    this.getPackageName());
            image.setImageResource(idDrawable);

            String rgname = "radioGroup"+i;
            int idRg = getResources().getIdentifier(rgname, "id",
                    this.getPackageName());
            RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(idRg);
            rg.removeAllViews();
            RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton(this);
            rb1.setId(i);
            rb1.setText(c.getString(1));
            rg.addView(rb1);
            RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton(this);
            rb2.setId(i+1);
            rb2.setText(c.getString(2));
            rg.addView(rb2);
            RadioButton rb3 = new RadioButton(this);
            rb3.setId(i+2);
            rb3.setText(c.getString(3));
            rg.addView(rb3);


            String nenun = "e" + i;
            String enun = c.getString(0);
            int idEnun = getResources().getIdentifier(nenun, "id",
                    this.getPackageName());
            TextView txtenun = (TextView) findViewById(idEnun);
            txtenun.setText(enun);

            i++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
```